# How to center search results in Less, instead of moving matched line to top of terminal

Tags: less

When searching for terms in less, I'd like to see lines above and below a search result. Can less be configured to do this?

Simple less usage is:
- Open file
- Search by typing "/"
- Move to new search matches with "n"
But each match is shown on the first line of the terminal. You can not see the lines that came just before a search result without moving the view back a few lines. It's tedious to do that as you skim through a file.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use the `-j` option. From within `less`, type <kbd>-</kbd> then <kbd>j</kbd> then enter a number of lines below the top of the screen for the target line to be displayed (e.g. 12).

You can start `less` using this option:

```
less -j12
```

or set the `LESS` environment variable to include it:

```
export LESS=-j12
```

My `$LESS` is:

```
-iMFXRj4a#1
```

You can include setting the environment variable in your `~/.bashrc` file to make it persistent.

Comment: -j.5 causes "middle of screen".

Comment: A dot followed by a number is a decimal fraction, i.e. `.5` means 50% of the screen height.